# RabbitMQ dual consumers one master and other slave

Tags: c#, windows-services, rabbitmq, easynetq

I am currently trying to tackle a case where I need 2 windows services running on different servers one will be considered a master and will do all the processing whilst the other would only be checking if the master has fallen.

This is necessary as there were cases where the server itself fell and thus the recovery option of restarting the service was not enough.

My knowledge on RabbitMQ isn't that great although I had thought of something along the lines of.

1. On start call queue to check if master service exists.
2. If last message is more than parameter x elect self as master service.
3. Else if no record exists elect self as master.
4. If master exists continue to check queue every y seconds.
5. While master continues to exist then continue pinging every y secs.
6. Else elect self.

I wanted to know if anyone has every had a similar scenario and if they have what approach did they take. Although any general suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need a master-slave architecture here? why can't you just have more than 1 consumers? if one fails, there are others that are still working.

Comment: It seems the way the system was originally designed wouldn't allow two item working in parallel. Due to factors such as messages needing to be processed in sequence.